# Eclipse CDT parser support for c++14

Tags: eclipse, c++14, eclipse-cdt

Good old disconnect between what the compiler deems valid and what the IDE thinks... Before you introduce duplicate questions / answers, I must stress that *everything* available on the issue here and elsewhere I have already tried and distilled to this setup:

- install latest eclipse CDT - Oxygen 4.7.2 / build id 20171218-0600
- gcc 6.1 only compiler visible in system path - defaults to c++14 standard without the need for explicit `-std` flag

Checking the log for compiler settings discovery, it's configured correctly for C++14:

```
03:51:39 **** Running scanner discovery: CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW ****
g++ -E -P -v -dD C:/dev/eclipse-oxy-cpp/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-6.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw610/x86_64-610-posix-seh-rt_v5/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-isl-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw610/x86_64-610-posix-seh-rt_v5/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw610/x86_64-610-posix-seh-rt_v5/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/c/mingw610/x86_64-610-posix-seh-rt_v5/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw610/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-P' '-v' '-dD' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2' '-march=nocona'
 C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/cc1plus.exe -E -quiet -v -P -iprefix C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT C:/dev/eclipse-oxy-cpp/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C -mtune=core2 -march=nocona -dD
#define __STDC__ 1
#define __cplusplus 201402L
(etc)
```

The following snippet compiles (with unused variable warning but nonetheless), but eclipse highlights issues with resolving `test` in `int main`:

```cpp
auto test (auto N) {return N;}
int main () {
  auto z = test( 3U );
  return 0;
}
```

The parser log gives:

```
Unresolved names:
   Attempt to use symbol failed: test in file ...
```

The IDE shows this in *problems*:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? test(?)
'
```

For all intents and purposes eclipse **is in fact seeing the correct gcc binary, and is using the correct c++ standard, but still not conforming to the compiler** per evidence above (unless I missed something?).

Any ideas how to make eclipse behave with syntax parsing given it's already got the right c++ standard version?

I get the feeling it's an issue with the indexer rather than the parser, since it has no trouble figuring out the number of arguments or the declaration but can't seem to make sense of functions with `auto` return type that depends on an auto-typed argument.

**UPDATE**

It may be related to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408470) (looks to be fixed) and [this followup bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529303) (still ongoing, test case given is similar to mine).

However, this version of `test` does not give me problems, so I'm unsure if it's the same bug or something else...

```cpp
template< typename T > auto test (T N) {return N;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto` in the parameter type of a function (as opposed to a lambda) is not standard C++14.

It's supported by the Concepts TS (which is supported by GCC >= 6 with the `-fconcepts` flag), and accepted by GCC >= 4.9 even without `-fconcepts` **as an extension**, but it's not standard. (It may become standard in C++20, along with some other parts of the Concepts TS.)

For example, here's what Clang (which does not support this extension) says about your code in C++14 mode:

```
test.cpp:1:12: error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype
auto test (auto N) {return N;}
           ^~~~
```

Eclipse CDT does not currently implement this extension either. I filed [bug 532085](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532085) to track adding support for it; contributions are welcome!

Comment: Re-reading what Concepts TS introduces, you are correct sir... What I'm unsure of now is how / why gcc accepts this without the `-fconcepts` flag; without it I'd expect to see what clang did. I know that `gnu++NN` vs `c++NN` enables gcc extensions, and the default is `gnu++14`, would that be it?

Comment: @XerenNarcy: It appears gcc accepts this with either `-std=c++14` or `-std=gnu++14`. Perhaps the gcc developers view its absence in C++14 as a defect (though this view is not shared by the standards committee). I've noticed that gcc tends to be more permissive about extensions in general than clang; I guess this is another instance of that.